# Google places autocomplete - adding custom result as last suggestion

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

I'm using google places autocomplete to show location suggestions for users. I have added a custom result to the autocomplete suggestions using the following code -

```
$timeout(function(){
                    var el = angular.element('<div id="cantFind" class="pointer m-b-5">Can\'t find your location?</div>');
                    angular.element(".pac-container").append(el);
                    el.bind("mousedown", function() {
                        $scope.setEnterManualView(true);
                    });
                }, 2000);
```

Problem here is the "Can't find your location?" option comes at random order in suggestions. I want it to come at the end only as the last suggestion. Something like this -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching quite a lot, it looks like there is no such direct way to do this. The only way I could do this is by modifying the CSS such that "Can't find your location?" comes at the bottom. Here is the CSS I used :

```
.location-autocomplete-container{
  &:after{
    padding-top:47px;
  }
  .cant-find-location{
    font-size: 13px;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom:16px;
    left:0;
    i{
      font-size: 1.2em;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
  }
}
```